# How to get sliders into the Components window - CodeNameOne

Tags: java, codenameone

I am developing my first application. It looks great and I am completely happy with it, however, I need the values from a couple of sliders in order to complete the code.

The problem I am having is simply `int slide.getvalue(); .getIncrement();` etc does not work. The button I am programming is on the same form as the sliders, but the sliders do not show in the components list from the userclasses (coding area), however, they do show in the Generated (StateMachineBase.java).

I simply need to store the increment selected by the user into a int variable. Please help.

The application includes:

- 6 forms
- Sliders and button on individual form
- Customised Theme

Comment: Without seeing the code it would be dificult to help you.

Comment: What code would you like? I went into theme.res, created a form, and placed sliders in a container (setup as a grid). I then made a submit button and clicked on action event. No coding has been done yet, as I am trying to get the values from the sliders.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiarized with codenameone. So, if there isn't code, I can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume slider name is SliderTest and you have added by designer then in coding area you can access by FindSliderTest()

You can write following code in form's before event to get value. Say you have myForm then

`@Override
    protected void beforeMyForm(Form f) {
        findSliderTest(f).addDataChangedListener(new DataChangedListener() {
            public void dataChanged(int type, final int index) {
                Log.p("type="+type+" index="+index);
            }
        }
    }`

here index represents the actual value/position of your slider.

Comment: and to set slider to some exact value you can use
findSliderTest().setProgress(50);
or whatever number. To get value you can use findSliderTest().getProgress();

Comment: findSliderTest().getProgress(); . I get can't find symbol? Thanks for your help btw

Comment: what name did you give to slider ? and if you havn't modified the name of slider then you can access it by findSlider();

Comment: This whole thing was because I named the slider "Slider_name" The underscore is not required based on the component list. Thank you Akash :) You really helped me out.

Comment: @JSint great to hear it worked for you. Click the checkbox next to the answer to accept it